# Install ember@1.13.13 on Windows 7 and it keeps hanging on the extract of bower

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I'm trying to "npm install -g ember@1.13.13" on Windows 7 and it keeps hanging on the extract of bower. I've tried clearing the npm cache and the bower cache but it still hangs. I'm installing that specific version of ember as that is the version required for the project I'm involved with. Here is the command window output;

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g ember-cli@1.13.13
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls gracef
ul-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@3.10.2: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated socket.io-pure@1.3.12: socket.io-pure is no longer maintained as the original socket.io removed all native dependencies. Please use the original.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.3.0: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated engine.io-pure@1.5.9: engine.io-purce is no longer maintained as the original engine.io removed all native dependencies. Please use the original.
npm WARN deprecated socket.io-client-pure@1.3.12: socket.io-client-pure is no longer maintained as the original socket.io removed all native dependencies. Please use the original.
npm WARN deprecated ws-pure@0.8.0: ws-pure is no longer maintained as the original ws removed all native dependencies. Please use the original ws.
npm WARN deprecated engine.io-client-pure@1.5.9: engine-io-client-pure is no longer maintained as the original engine-io-client removed all native dependencies. Please use the orig
inal.
extract:bower             ▌ ╢██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
```

These are the installed versions of
node: v4.4.7
npm: 3.3.12
bower: 1.7.9

Comment: You should always install the latest version of `ember-cli` global. If you are in a project folder `ember-cli` will always use the local installed version. Also you can use a much more recent `ember-cli` version with an old `ember` version.

Comment: Installing the current version of ember worked. Oh well, I guess I'll have to ensure I don't use any feature beyond 1.13.13.

Comment: You can't do so. As I told you, if you are in a project folder ember will always use the local version. The global one does just redirect the command.

Comment: There are two different things: ember-cli version and you app version. As Lux said, install the latest version of ember-cli. Since your app stayed at ember version 1.13.13, you will be use every feature of it.

Comment: @Lux I'm not working on a traditional project in the sense that I forked it from GithHub and the project contains a package.json file that contains a requirement of ember-cli@1.131.3. I don't own the Ember app that the project I'm involved in works with. The project is a Chrome extension for the Ember app. Maybe I'm making much ado about nothing.

What I'm trying to do is learn more about how an Ember app can be "extended" externally. We'd love to have an Ember guru join the party. In case you're interested. Check it out here [link](https://github.com/toolkit-for-ynab/toolkit-for-ynab)